# Issue in Scrolling the Tableview to the Bottom of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a issue in Scrolling the Tableview as when i scroll tableview to the Bottom ,after a Certain point ,that Cell Row will Hide and then if I again scroll back to top it Show up .

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(ProfileViewControllerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCellIdentifier)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,650.0,0.0);
}
```

and then i am using a Tableview Cell (custom Cell)like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = (self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ProfileViewControllerCell)!
    return Cell
}
```

Any Help if will really great as i got struck on this one for a while , let me know if you want any additional information 
Thanks

Comment: You are putting 650 point bottom inset